# Why does the bot on Telethon, when authorized as a user, not respond to messages?

Tags: python, telethon

I'm creating a chatbot autoresponder that should respond to messages based on a template. The script is up and running:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

from config import API_ID, API_HASH, BOT_TOKEN

api_id = API_ID
api_hash = API_HASH
bot_token = BOT_TOKEN

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i)hello.+'))
async def main(event):
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

    await event.reply('Hey!')

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

But the user, under whom it is authorized with API_ID and API_HASH, is not responding. And it doesn't give any errors. It's as if nothing is working at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error in the code is that the `client.run_until_disconnected()` method is not a valid method in the `TelegramClient` class.

To resolve the problem, you should replace the line `client.run_until_disconnected()` with `client.start()` to start the client and keep it running until it is disconnected. Here's the corrected code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

from config import API_ID, API_HASH, BOT_TOKEN

api_id = API_ID
api_hash = API_HASH
bot_token = BOT_TOKEN

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i)hello.+'))
async def main(event):
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

    await event.reply('Hey!')

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Make sure you have the required values for `API_ID`, `API_HASH`, and `BOT_TOKEN` defined in your `config.py` file.